# Are the weights between hidden layers changed in backwards propogation? If so, how

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

If so, I don't understand how, as a large part of back propogation is knowing what the 'real' answer is in comparison to 'predicted' answer. With 1 neuron in a hidden layer, we do not know the 'real answer' so theoretically it is impossible unless another technique is employed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What the backpropagation is computing, is the derivative (gradient) of that final output with respect to each neuron and each weight in the metwork.

This isn't a problem! You can think of it as computing the derivative of $f(g(x;w_1);w_2)$, once with respect to $w_2$, and once with respect for $w_1$. Do note that $f$ and $g$ would be very simple functions for which this computation can be done efficiently.

For example, if we set $f(a;w_2):=a+w_2$ and $g(x,w;1):= x+2w_1$, then $f(g(x;w_1);w_2)=x+2w_1+w_2$, and the derivatives by $w_1$ and $w_2$ would be $2$ and $1$ respectively. Do note though, that in a real scenario, the functions are a bit more complicated and you might needore thought about how to compute the gradients (hence the backpropagation algorithm)

Comment: Thank you, but just to clarify, do I only work out dC/dB and dC/dW on the output neurons? thanks

Comment: If $C$ here means the loss of the network, then yes. To be exact, you compute $\frac{d\left(loss(f(x_{inp};\theta),y_{inp})\right)}{d\theta}$ where $f$ is the neural network, $x_{inp},y_{inp}$ are the input data and label, and $\theta$ is the network parameter which stands for either $W$ and $B$ - which are the weights and biases of **all** of the neurons in the network (not just the output ones).

Comment: Thx! This is the answer I was looking for

Comment: one last question. Do the weights that are in between hidden layers change during backpropogation?

Comment: Yes, every weight changes during the learning step. Even if they are "hidden". The name "hidden" does mot really mean we don't see the neurons, it just means they aren't in the first or the last layers.

Comment: Thanks, I understand now

Comment: Also, is there a formula for how the hidden weights change?

Comment: That formula is precisely what the backpropagation computes. It depends on the specific architecture of the neural network (how many layers, the size of the layers, which activation function is used, etc.) - so you won't find a closed formula for this (but you can derive one by hand for any *specific* neural network)

Comment: Ok but please could you maybe just link an article (if you have one) that explains it? If you don't don't worry I'll find one

Comment: [this site](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap1.html) shows a through explanation of neural networks (along with an explanation on backpropagation) with actual code for it

Answer (score 1):

Backpropagation computes the gradient of the loss function (with respect to the weights).  Then, the weights are updated using this gradient.  There are many tutorials on how back propagation works.  Note that supervised learning assumes all training set instances are labelled, so we *do* know what the real answer is for each sample in the training set; the loss function is computed based on the extent to which the prediction matches (or does not match) this real answer.

Comment: Thanks, but when I said that we don't have the real answers I meant for each neuron, and also I can't find anything online that shows how to backpropogate a neuron not in the output layer?